# How to send data from Adonis js API to fabric-sample ledger of Hyperledger fabric?

Tags: node.js, typescript, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, adonis.js

I am trying to send data from my Adonis js application to fabric-sample ledger but getting below error, i am not able to make connection between these two technologies.

> ERROR: [18:08:05.471] ERROR (my-app/12688): No client connection
> supplied
> err: {
> "type": "Error",
> "message": "No client connection supplied",
> "stack":
> Error: No client connection supplied
> at internalConnect (C:\Users\archi\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\DSA-Backend\my-app\node_modules@hyperledger\fabric-gateway\src\gateway.ts:147:15)
> at connect (C:\Users\archi\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\DSA-Backend\my-app\node_modules@hyperledger\fabric-gateway\src\gateway.ts:138:12)
> at LedgerService.createAsset (C:\Users\archi\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\DSA-Backend\my-app\app\Services\BuySell\LedgerService.ts:13:25)
> at EkobonController.submit (C:\Users\archi\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\DSA-Backend\my-app\app\Controllers\Http\BuySell\EkobonController.ts:121:25)
> at Injector.callAsync (C:\Users\archi\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\DSA-Backend\my-app\node_modules@adonisjs\fold\build\src\Ioc\Injector.js:124:30)
> "status": 500
> }

i am trying to send the data from Adonis js application to fabric-sample ledger.

Expectation, data should be send to the ledger.

Actual result, i am facing

> error: [18:08:05.471] ERROR (my-app/12688): No client connection
> supplied